# Container of Functions with different Parameters

Tags: c++, function, templates, pointers, containers

Is there a way to store void functions with different parameters in a vector? The number of parameters is always one, only the type differs. The parameter type can be a default type like `int`, a pointer to my own object like `example*` or any other type.

What I do for now is using a vector of functions with a void pointer as parameter. So I can pass everything. But I want to get rid of the back casting in all the functions.

```
unordered_map<string, function<void(void*)> > List;

void Callback(string Name, function<void(void*)> Function)
{
    List[Name].push_back(&Function);
}

Callback("event", [](void* x){
    int value = *(int*)x;
    cout << value << endl;
});
```

Here is an example to illustrate what I would like to have. Please note the template syntax I would prefer. Therefore I would need to store all the functions in a container.

```
vector<function<void(...)> > List; // need something other than a std vector

template <typename T>
void Callback(string Name, function<void(T)> Function)
{
    List[Name].push_back(&Function);
}

Callback<int>([](int x){
    cout << x << endl;
});
```

This application is performance related since it is an essential part of a realtime rendering engine.

Edit: I solved the point of storing functions without parameters, so this is not part of the question anymore what makes the question more clear and straightforward.

Comment: At the call site, how do you know which argument type to use?

Comment: For now, it is a void pointer, too. But I would like to templatize that, too.

Comment: The interesting bit of information is how do you *know* which type to use, not how do you currently represent it. Assume that you have `vector<Foo> v` where `Foo` is just the right type. You want to call `v[3](x)`. What type do you *want* `x` to be?

Comment: There is a constraint for all callback functions to have either no or the same parameter as the event provides. For example the event `WindowResize` provides a `Vector2i` for the new height and width. All registered callbacks must have none or just a `Vector2i` parameter. But as I said my actual implementation uses void pointers so only the programmer knows the type.

Comment: So the programmer knows that `WindowResize` has data of type `Vector2i` etc, and he wants to express this knowledge using only statically type safe constructs of the language. Why he lumps all callbacks of all possible types in the same vector then? By doing this, he throws away the knowledge. Why not separate callbacks that accept an `int` from those that accept `Vector2i` etc in a different variables, of different types? Then each event type will know where to find relevant callbacks.

Comment: Right, I can't use different lists because what I am working on is something like a system or framework for several future applications. The system can't know all possible types of the future application. So different lists are not practical. But I could imagine, saving the type name as a string besides the object itself to remain typesafety. But this isn't the point now. I just would like to learn **how to store these different functions in the same vector using templates**. Is this even possible? A solution internally using void pointers would be acceptable for me.

Comment: You seem to already have a solution that uses void pointers. `vector` stores objects which are all of the same type. You cannot throw in the word `template` and magically make it not so.

Comment: My actual solution uses `vector<function<void(void*)> >` but not `vector<void*>` because I can't pass the functions by reference and otherwise they won't exist for long. I caught that a vector can store objects of different type. Therefore I need another container, right? Which container can I use? It is strongly performance related since it is the main part of a realtime engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I developed a void pointer based event system and it works now. It uses templates for passing and receiving data. Functions with none or one parameter of any type both are supported. Since it uses void pointers to store the callback functions I suppose it is very fast compared to a solution using the any type from boost framework.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <functional> 
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class ManagerEvent
{
    typedef unordered_map<string, unordered_map<int, vector<pair<void*, bool> > > > Events;
public:
    void Listen(string Name, function<void()> Function)
    {
        Listen(Name, 0, Function);
    }
    void Listen(string Name, int State, function<void()> Function)
    {
        List[Name][State].push_back(make_pair(new function<void()>(Function), false));
    }
    template <typename T>
    void Listen(string Name, function<void(T)> Function)
    {
        Listen<T>(Name, 0, Function);
    }
    template <typename T>
    void Listen(string Name, int State, function<void(T)> Function)
    {
        List[Name][State].push_back(make_pair(new function<void(T)>(Function), true));
    }
    void Fire(string Name)
    {
        Fire(Name, 0);
    }
    void Fire(string Name, int State)
    {
        auto Functions = List[Name][State];

        for (auto i = Functions.begin(); i != Functions.end(); ++i)
        {
            if(i->second) continue;
            else          (*(function<void()>*)(i->first))();
        }
    }
    void FireRange(string Name, int From, int To)
    {
        for(int i = From; i <= To; ++i) Fire(Name, i);
    }
    template <typename T>
    void Fire(string Name, T Data)
    {
        Fire(Name, 0, Data);
    }
    template <typename T>
    void Fire(string Name, int State, T Data)
    {
        auto Functions = List[Name][State];

        for (auto i = Functions.begin(); i != Functions.end(); ++i)
        {
            if(i->second) (*(function<void(T)>*)i->first)(Data);
            else          (*(function<void()>*)i->first)();
        }
    }
private:
    Events List;
};
```

This is what came to my mind and it works quite well. However, please feel free to suggest improvements or use the code for your own projects.

Answer (score 1):

If type of parameters that could passed to the function is limited, then one option is using something like [boost::variant](http://www.boost.org/libs/variant/):

```
typedef boost::variant<
    std::function<void()>,
    std::function<void(int)>,
    std::function<void(long)>,
    std::function<void(std::string const&)>
> my_functions;
typedef std::vector<my_functions> functions_list;
```

Then you can insert your callbacks directly into container.

Comment: Sorry, I need to pass hole classes, not only default types. I updated my question for this fact.

Comment: Sorry I don't get your comment, could you please explain it!

Comment: Your introducing sentence does not apply. The types of parameters are not limited to `int`, `float`, `string`, ... I need to pass objects of my own classes.

Comment: I said you can use it if list of types are limited, but not limited to this set, this is just a sample, you may replace this types with any other types and your variant may have 50 different types. Please just read documentation of `boost::variant`.

Comment: Ah, I got it. But unfortunately this isn't practical, too. The event manager which handles the callbacks isn't related to a specific application. So it can't know all the needed types.

Comment: So you may use `boost::any` instead of `void*`, using it you can have safe cast and ensure that you are calling function with correct parameters

Answer (score 1):

As n.m pointed out in a comment, the issue is how you use the
value.  Formally, C++ allows you to convert any pointer to
(non-member) function to a `void (*)(void)` and back to its
original type, without loss of value—`void (*)(void)` can
be considered a sort of `void*` for pointers to functions.  And
practically, the runtime cost of such conversions is zero.  But
in order to use the function, at some point, you have to know 
the original type, in order to convert the pointer back to it.

You don't give your use case, but the usual situation involves
callbacks, where the registration of the callback has a `void
(*)( void* )` (or `void (*)( void const* )`), and the callback
converts the `void*` to the correct type, and calls a member
function on it.  In this case, using `void*` as the generic
argument is the correct (and probably the only) solution.

Of course, this is the C solution, and should usually only be
used when the interface using the callback is defined using the
C API (functions like `pthread_create`, for example).  In C++,
the solution is to register objects, which derive from the same
abstract base class, and implement a specific pure virtual
function.

Comment: Internally the event system can use void pointers. But I would like a way to get rid of converting back the parameter. Therefore I would like templates.

Comment: Well, it's fairly easy to wrap the functions in templates.  The problem is that usually, if you're using this idiom, it's because the interface is designed using a C API (otherwise, there are better solutions).  To pass a pointer to a function to a C API, the function must be `extern "C"`, and a template cannot be `extern "C"`.

Comment: Could you provide an example? By the way, I don't depend on any C API.