# Convert void* to std::function<void()>

Tags: c++, function, pointers, casting, std

Is store function pointers with different parameters in a vector of void pointers.

```
unordered_map<string, vector<void*> > List;

template <typename T>
void Listen(string Name, function<void(T)> Function)
{
    List[Name].push_back(&Function);
}
```

Then I want to call them, assuming that `T` is the same type for `Fire` as used for the `Listen`.

```
template <typename T>
void Fire(string Name, T Data)
{
    auto Functions = List[Name];

    for (auto i = Functions.begin(); i != Functions.end(); ++i)
    {
        (function<void(T)>)i)(Data);
    }
}
```

But I get a compiler error which reads `error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments in file ...\vc\include\xrefwrap 431 1`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're pushing the address of a parameter.

Comment: Why don't you save `std::function`'s in the `List`?

Comment: @Lol4t0. Sadly I can't save different types in the same list. For example `function<void(int)>`, `function<void(class*)>` and `function<void()>` are all different types.

Comment: @chill. Since it is a vector of void pointers what's wrong with that?

Comment: Yes, but you will not be able to determine the type of function when calling them also

Comment: _But you are not able to_. Given the pointer in the vector, you cannot get known whether it represents the function that fits you or not. You should save some additional information, consider using `boost::any` for example

Comment: @sharethis, this pointer becomes invalid once that function returns.

Comment: @sharethis `&Function` is a pointer to a local variable.  `List[Name].push_back(&Function);` now contains a pointer to random crap after the method ends.

Comment: Check out this similar question with an answer to this question here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/13763920/1079110

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one, you're taking the address of a parameter, here:

```
List[Name].push_back(&Function);
```

Then you're trying to convert an iterator object to a `std::function` object here:

```
(function<void(T)>)i)
```

What you trying to do can be done, like this, although it's not pretty, to put it mildly:

```
unordered_map<string, vector<void*> > List;

template <typename T>
void Listen(string Name, function<void(T)> &Function)
{
    List[Name].push_back(&Function);
}

template <typename T>
void Fire(string Name, T Data)
{
    auto Functions = List[Name];

    for (auto i = Functions.begin(); i != Functions.end(); ++i)
    {
      function<void(T)> *ptr = *i;

      (*ptr) (Data);
    }
}
```

It can break in lot of ways, for example you have no control that the function, registered under some name in `Listen` is called with the correct argument in `Fire` - consider calling `Listen<int> ("foo", f);` and then doing `Fire<double> ("foo", 3.14);`

Another approach - just pass closures for callbacks:

```
unordered_map<string, std::vector<function<void()> > > List;

void Listen(string Name, function<void()> Function)
{
    List[Name].push_back(Function);
}

void Fire(string Name)
{
    auto Functions = List[Name];

    for (auto i = Functions.begin(); i != Functions.end(); ++i)
      (*i) ();
}
```

Comment: Why is the `&` used on the parameter of the `Listen` function? Can I avoid that somehow?

Comment: This is needed to ensure the function is called with an lvalue, i.e. with something that has an address. Still have to make sure that address stays valid as long as it's in the vector/map.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <functional>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

template<typename T> struct BlockDeduction{typedef T type;};
struct BaseCallback {
  virtual ~BaseCallback();
  template<typename T>
  void DoCall( typename BlockDeduction<T>::type&& t ) const;
};
template<typename T>
struct Callback: BaseCallback
{
  std::function<void(T)> func;
  Callback( std::function<void(T)> const& f ):func(f) {}
};


template<typename T>
void BaseCallback::DoCall( typename BlockDeduction<T>::type&& t ) const {
  Assert( dynamic_cast<Callback<T>const*>(this) );
  static_cast<Callback<T>const*>(this).func(std::forward(t));
}

typedef std::unique_ptr<BaseCallback> upCallback;
template<typename T>
upCallback make_callback( std::function<void(T)> const& f ) {
  return upCallback( new Callback<T>( f ) );
}


struct Listener {
  std::unordered_map< std::string, std::vector<upCallback>> List;
  template<typename T>
  void Listen( std::string Name, std::function<void(T)> f) {
    List[Name].push_back( make_callback(f) );
  }
  template<typename T>
  void Fire( std::string Name, typename BlockDeduction<T>::type&& t ) {
    auto callbacks = List.find(Name);
    if (callbacks == List.end()) return;
    for(auto it = callbacks->second.begin(); it != callbacks->second.end(); ++it) {
      if (it +1 = callbacks->second.end())
      {
        (**it).DoCall<T>( std::forward(t) );
      } else {
        (**it).DoCall<T>( t );
      }
    }
  }
};
```

... or something like that.

This stores a copy of the `std::function` in the map, wrapped up generically.  Memory is handled via a `unique_ptr`.  I carefully blocked type deduction at points where the type must be exactly what you used when you installed the `Listener` (automatic type deduction at that point is rather fragile).

In debug, you'll get an assertion failure if you violate the Name<->type mapping.

Some extra work needs to be done for nullary callbacks.  Just write a `DoCall` that casts `BaseCallback` to `Callback<void>`, specialize `Callback<void>` to be a nullary `function` wrapper, specialize `make_callback` on nullary `function`, and write a `Fire(string)` method for `Listener` that calls the bare `DoCall`.

Or create a `struct Empty` and use lambdas to wrap nullary functions in `function<void(Empty)>`, which would involve slightly less code, but would be slower at run-time.

Comment: I like that but I need some time to truly understand everything you did.

Comment: Note that the `std::forward` crap might be wrong -- I'm still trying to grok it.  I probably shouldn't have included it, and just done some redundant copies of type `T`.  `BlockDeduction` only exists to block automatic function type deduction (because the `T` that `Fire` takes must match EXACTLY the same type as the `T` `Listen` takes, or undefined behavior results).  The `BaseCallback` really exists in order to just have a virtual dtor (so its child class dtor is called), and the `DoCall` method is just putting the dangerous `static_cast` inside the class.  `unique_ptr` manages lifetime.